# Why does $location.search lag one iteration behind when being used in lodash' _.debounce()

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I had the following snippet:

```
$scope.$watch('filters', _.debounce(function(newValue, oldValue) {

    $location.search({test : newValue}).replace();

}, 500), true);
```

What happens is that the url only gets updated on the second iteration and then lags behind one iteration. Meaning the second time it shows the first, etc...

Any clue on why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `loDash` `_.debounce` has a third `options` parameter which has a `leading` option that is `false` by default. [See](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce).

Try:

```
$scope.$watch('filters', _.debounce(function(newValue, oldValue) {    

    $location.search({test : newValue}).replace();

}, 500, {leading: true}), true);
```

Comment: ok got it, thanks for that. I didn't quite understand those parameters when I looked at the docs. Checked the source, get it now.